# Is there a way to see how far off a badge you are

Tags: discussion, badges

Is there some way that I can see how far off a badge I am.

Lets say I currently have the bronze badge for `.net` and am striving towards the silver. It would be nice to know how far off I am.

You could argue that people shouldn't be answering just to get a badge but it also promotes more answers.

Comment: there is a query for that: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/2357/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-towards-tag-specialist-badges  I was watching it for a while as I closed in on my silver in VB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the badge.

In this case - progress towards tag badges - you can see by going to your profile and hovering over the number in front of the tag:

[image]

and the tooltip will tell you how many non-wiki answers you have and what the total score is. You can then relate to the tag badge thresholds.

It's the second sentence:

> Gave [nnn] non-wiki answers with a total score of [tttt].

If you want to find out via search use the following:

> user:me is:answer wiki:no [tag-name]

Just for completeness here are the thresholds for the tag badges:

> - Bronze Badge - You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
> - Silver Badge - You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
> - Gold Badge - You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

Comment: Ahh... those hidden mouseover tips... learn something new every day.

Comment: @MichaelT you should always hover over UI elements (clickable or not) you'd be surprised at what you discover.

Comment: That hover over only gives metrics for asked questions. I need to know the number that I have answered.

Comment: @MattWilko the second sentence beginning with "Gave 192 non-wiki answers" in Chris's example.

Comment: @MichaelT - apologies I missed that

Answer (score 4):

Tag badges are rather 'easy' to do.  The silver badge is 400 score and 80 answers.  Searching for the tag, user, and is answer ([user:500974 [.net] is:answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A500974+%5B.net%5D+is%3Aanswer)) will tell you how many answers you have in that tag.  Compare this to the tag score:

[image: tag score section]

And you'll have an idea of what you need to work on.  The tag score shown there only shows answer score.

For .net, you've got 146 answers with a total score of 163.  You'll need another 237 up votes on answers to get the silver badge there.

Comment: Thanks but I don't get the results you posted when I click on that link. I get each individual answer with that tag not the sum of votes

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to use the Choose Your Badge screen from your user profile.
But it doesn't seem to include the tag badges.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tag badge is only available for choosing after you reached 20k, and it locates on the reputation section.

Comment: It leaves out tag badges because [Unicorn thought that was a good idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254052/cant-track-tag-badges-without-20k-rep). CC @nhahtdh.